# Sum amounts in one table and join total amount from other table

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I'm not the most SQL savvy here, but I am trying to join two tables (one with expense data & one with budget data). I can't seem to figure out the right code to sum the expenses by field, and then join that with the budget amount for those specific fields.

Here's an example of data that I'm working with:

```
Expenses Table
BudgetAccount    Department    Entity   Date       Amount
Other Expenses   Finance       A        9/1/2019   100
Other Expenses   Finance       A        9/1/2019   300
Other Expenses   Finance       A        9/1/2019   50
Utilities        Finance       A        9/1/2019   200
Utilities        Construction  B        9/1/2019   300
Insurance        Construction  B        9/1/2019   400
Legal            HR            A        9/1/2019   500
Other Expenses   HR            A        9/1/2019   100
Legal            HR            A        9/1/2019   50

Budget Table
BudgetAccount    Department    Entity   Date       Amount
Other Expenses   Finance       A        9/1/2019   500
Utilities        Finance       A        9/1/2019   200
Insurance        Construction  B        9/1/2019   450
Utilities        Construction  B        9/1/2019   400
Legal            HR            A        9/1/2019   800
Other Expenses   HR            A        9/1/2019   50
```

This is the final product that I'm trying to get to:

```
BudgetAccount    Department    Entity   Date       Actual   Budget
Other Expenses   Finance       A        9/1/2019   450      500
Utilities        Finance       A        9/1/2019   200      200
Insurance        Construction  B        9/1/2019   400      450
Utilities        Construction  B        9/1/2019   300      400
Legal            HR            A        9/1/2019   550      800
Other Expenses   HR            A        9/1/2019   100      50
```

I have tried the following code:

```
SELECT e.budgetaccount, e.department, e.entity, e.date, SUM(e.amount) AS Actual, b.amount
FROM expenses AS e
  INNER JOIN (SELECT b.budgetaccount, b.department, b.entity, b.date, b.amount FROM budget AS b)
  ON e.budgetaccount = b.budgetaccount
  AND e.department = b.department
  AND e.entity = b.entity
  AND e.date = b.date
GROUP BY e.budgetaccount, e.department, e.entity, e.date
```

. . . and this is the error I'm getting when I'm trying to run the query in Tableau:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POiP5.png)

I'm sure there are quite a few errors in the coding that I've tried so poorly to do above, but any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have error? ..show thexac error message... wrong result ..show your actual result too

Comment: Whats the error you got?

Comment: I've updated the post to show the error message I'm getting in Tableau.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found two issue

1) wrong position for table name alias b

2 ) you need al the column not in aggregation function mentione din group  by

```
SELECT e.budgetaccount, e.department, e.entity, e.date, SUM(e.amount) AS Actual, b.amount
FROM expenses AS e
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT budgetaccount
  , department
  , entity
  , date
  , amount 
  FROM budget
)  b ON e.budgetaccount = b.budgetaccount
      AND e.department = b.department
        AND e.entity = b.entity
        AND e.date = b.date
GROUP BY e.budgetaccount, e.department, e.entity, e.date, b.amount
```

anyway you could avoid subquery for budget table  ..

```
SELECT e.budgetaccount, e.department, e.entity, e.date, SUM(e.amount) AS Actual, b.amount
FROM expenses AS e
LEFT JOIN budget b ON e.budgetaccount = b.budgetaccount
      AND e.department = b.department
        AND e.entity = b.entity
        AND e.date = b.date
GROUP BY e.budgetaccount, e.department, e.entity, e.date, b.amount
```

Comment: Follow up question, @scaisEdge . . . although your code does work, it does not show budget data for months where there are no expenses. For example, we have budget amounts in November, but no expenses have been incurred yet. Is there a way to include budget amounts for upcoming months? I would think an INNER JOIN would work, but that returns no data.

Comment: you need  a table  for all the months  ...  you can build a dinamic table using a sets of union for each month or create a dummy table with the(all)  month you need  and the from this list month left join the others  table ... hope my comment is clear

Comment: I'm having troubles figuring out how to code it. Would you mind expounding?

Comment: the best way is post a specific question about this problem  .. with a clear data sample , the code you are using and  the expected  result ....

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only error you might have got would be `not a group by etc.` because of the no of rows not matching with budgetamount rows you should put a max on budget amount. Infact, the inner join would have given the 2nd table records as output but the fact that the column amount and budget amount columns no of records are different hence the data would be either redundant or more depending on which table columns has more records therefore all the first table records is the inner join's actual o/p here and putting a group by on it will reduce the actual amount rows by sum aggregation but keeping table budget amount columns records as more as theres no aggregation etc. Although table budget account has only 1 budget amount for each unique row in first table but that doesnt mean that there cant be multiple in worst cases so group by expects an aggregate on budgetamount column as well to keep the data consistent

```
   Select... max(b.amount)..
   Rest the same query
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you were close in your query. Doesn't appear to be a need for the sub select and need to add additional SUM

```
    SELECT e.budgetaccount, e.department, e.entity, e.date, SUM(e.amount) AS Actual, SUM(b.amount) as budget
    FROM expenses AS e
    JOIN budget AS b
      ON e.budgetaccount = b.budgetaccount
      AND e.department = b.department
      AND e.entity = b.entity
      AND e.date = b.date
    GROUP BY e.budgetaccount, e.department, e.entity, e.date
```